# How do I embed a Vimeo video in a Flash AS2 site?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

How do I embed a Vimeo video in a Flash AS2 site? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From vimeo forum itself:

This search:
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&hs=w8z&rls=es-LA&q=vimeo+video+inside+flash+movie&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=

Lead me to:

http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:6387

In which they discuss this topic